# Import-SPWeb : Access is denied

Tags: import

We were able to export site backup and when we are trying to import content of backup file to newly created site collection we are encountering with below error message which says access denied.

Import-SPWeb : Access is denied

We uses the SharePoint form account to run the script.

Comment: under which account you running the powershell, could you please login to site collection with same account and see if you can access the site...also check the Event Log / ULS log if you get more information from there...i.e where is getting access denied

Comment: I could access the site with that account however still unable to import..

Comment: run the powershell console as Administrator and then try again...
If still issue then share the ULS logs / application log.

Comment: run the command "whoami" in powershell. This will give you the user account which runs the scripts. Check if this user has enough permissions.

Comment: Fixed the issue by Saving it as a Template